# RSA, CLR, BouncyCastle и непонятно что

Tags: c#, криптография, rsa, clr

Добрый день! Бьюсь не один день над проблемой шифрования данных. На каждом шагу новые трудности. В итоге получила работающую версию WinForm с таким кодом:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\...\ublic.cer"); //Надо указать путь к pem  файлу  
PemReader pr = new PemReader(sr);  
CspParameters RSAParams = new CspParameters();  
RSAParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;  
RsaKeyParameters KeyPair = (RsaKeyParameters)pr.ReadObject();  
RSAParameters rsapar = new RSAParameters();  
sr.Close();  
rsapar.Modulus = KeyPair.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();  
rsapar.Exponent = KeyPair.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();  
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, RSAParams);  
rsa.ImportParameters(rsapar);  
///////// Вот строка, в которой появляется ошибка  
byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textBox1.Text), false);  
//////  
string encdate = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);  
textBox4.Text =encdate;
```

Все работает. Создаю CLR, размещаю на сервере, перекладываю ключи, куда положено, и начинаю тихо радоваться, что все заработает.
Но! При запуске функции, которая создалась на основе сборки, получаю ошибку:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key not valid for
>   use in specified state.
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32
>   hr) at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._EncryptKey(SafeKeyHandle
>   hPubKey, Byte[] key) at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(Byte[]
>   rgb, Boolean fOAEP) at UserDefinedFunctions.fn_fk1_getdata(String str,
>   String url) .

Что не так? При создании веб-сервиса, шифрование тоже работает, а вот именно в сборке - проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего у пользователя, под которым код выполняется не хватает прав чтобы доступиться до "C:...\ublic.cer". Скорей всего веб-сервис выполняется под NetworkService, проверьте что у него есть права на чтение этого файла.

Answer (score 0):

При шифровании используется только сертификат (закрытый ключ используется для расшифровки). Поэтому, если ошибка на строке:

```
///////// Вот строка, в которой появляется ошибка  
byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textBox1.Text), false);  
//////
```

То, предполагаю, что дело в том, что в сборке другой сертификат, открытый ключ из которого не предназначен для шифрования данных (назначение открытого и закрытого ключей задаётся в сертификате).